# Execute an AsyncTask after Activity is shown

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm developing an Android 3.1 application.

I want to execute an `AsyncTask` after activity is shown. I want to show something to user before execute `AsyncTask`.

I've read that it is not recommend to execute `AsyncTask` on `onCreate()`.

Where I have to execute `AsyncTask` on `onStart()` or `onResume()`?

I want to left enough time to show activity before execute it.

Comment: @user370305 Oh, sorry. I've read that it is not recommend to run AsyncTask on onCreate()

Comment: `onStart()` is **NOT** called after the views are drawn to the screen.

Comment: That's not true. At that stage no view is rendered on screen. The view's at this point are only inflated and attached to the `Activity` root view. [setContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int))

Comment: The screen is rendered after `onResume()`. Try putting in debug points on `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` and watch your device. You'll see the screen isn't rendered until after `onResume()`.

Comment: @Graeme - onStart()  Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.

Followed by onResume() if the activity comes to the foreground, or onStop() if it becomes hidden. Means your all inflated view are rendering and is now displaying to user.

Comment: Try it yourself if you don't believe me. onStart() - "becoming visible" != "is now visible", infact it logically precludes the view being visible at that point as if it's visible it cannot be in the state of "becoming visible". Again - The proof is in the pudding - try it yourself, it's not difficult to prove.

Comment: Its not about believing. You are right, But the What I want to say is, when onStart() is called your activity view is ready to visible. So no more infalter of views are pending. And also the method what have you suggested in your answer is also calling before view is appear on the screen.

Comment: @Graeme - Anyway thanks for your replying and sharing info.

Answer (score 11):

`onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` are lifecycle methods called by the operating system and shouldn't be called directly. You can however override them to have your code executed at these stages of the activities lifecycle:

[image]

However, if you want your AsyncTask to start after all of your `View`s have been inflated and drawn to the screen then you need to put the code in this:

```
    toReturn.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            toReturn.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            // asyncTask.execute();
        }
    });
```

In the above example `toReturn` is a view in your onCreate() method. It can be any view you like.

This pulls a `ViewTreeObserver` from the View and add's a listener to it which will be called when the view has finished being drawn to the screen. It's important you keep the "removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()` line in as this will stop the code firing **every** time the View is drawn.

Comment: Bless you!
I've been having a similar issue with a certain command that wouldn't run from within "OnCreate()" or even "OnResume()" because the interface wasn't loaded yet so various methods returned null, and this sovled it (even without using async task!) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in `onResume()`

I hade same requirement in my activity where i need to show some list with other buttons and images..
List were getting data from server so used AsyncTask for that..

But before that required to show empty listview and other part of the screen..

so first when it goes to `onCreate()` I set `empty arraylist` to listview's adapter then in `onResume()` call the Asynctask and in that task fill the ArrayList and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Then another problem occure..when i go to next activity and come back it always call the asynctask even if i dont require..

So had put some condition like `if(arrayList.size()==0)` then call asynctask `else` dont.

Answer (score 0):

You can put yur code in the onWindowsFocusChanged method. You can use a thread inside it to manage the timer to start your specific asynctask.
Be aware that this would be performed each time your activity have the focus, not only the first time you launch your activity (I don't know if this could be a problem for you).

Comment: Wouldn't your code be fired every time a toast or dialogue gained focus or every time the activity is resumed from being put in the background?

Comment: Yes indeed. The question is not enough detailed on that, but I've highlighted that this could be fired everytime the activity have the focus. If this is an issue, my approach should be discarded. I've used it, as an example, with success to start/resume a background music on the focus acquisition.

Comment: Good example of when to use it! :)

Answer (score -2):

implement a `View` object and override the `onDraw()`.
that way you'll know exactly when the first screen is visible to the user

Comment: This would put mean creating a custom view (or anonymous custom view) and polluting the `onDraw()` method with code that has nothing to do with it. See my answer for a (ugly but) better way to have code fire after a `View` is drawn.